# CommandBus Responsibilities, redis or kafka

Tags: typescript, apache-kafka, redis, event-sourcing

Hello I am trying to start studying about es, microservices and then I would like to know about the command bus I basically believe that his responsibility is just to execute the command handler?
does it necessarily have to be a queue?
can you make kafka as a command bus or redis?
I have a simple command bus implementation, but I would like to implement a command bus to be used the same command bus for 3 microservices, the way I did I would have to have a command bus for each ms, and register the commands and the commands handlers for each micro service

impl with typescript :

```
export class CommandBus<Command extends ICommand = ICommand>
  implements ICommandBus<Command> {
  private handlers = new Map<string, ICommandHandler<Command>>()

  public execute<T extends Command>(command: T): Promise<any> {
    const handler = this.handlers.get(command.constructor.name)
    if (!handler) throw new Error(``)
    return handler.execute(command)
  }

  public register(
    data: { commandHandler: ICommandHandler; command: Type<ICommand> }[],
  ): void {
    data.forEach(({command,commandHandler}) => {
            this.bind(commandHandler, command.name)
        })
  }

  private bind<T extends Command>(handler: ICommandHandler<T>, name: string) {
    this.handlers.set(name, handler)
  }
}
```

I would like to know what would be the best choice to have only one command bus for all microservices, using kafka? or is an implementation with redis enough? Could someone help me how can i do this?
if possible an example i would be very grateful

Comment: See the sample CQRS/ES code at https://www.cqrs.nu that I maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't need a command-bus/queue, instead send the commands from the user/client directly to the Commandhandler/aggregate.

Kafka is better suited for event-driven architectures, where various services post events representing thins that happened and then for other services to consume.

Also, CQRS/EventSourcing are patterns you apply within one service (bounded context) and not across multiple services. You can use events to communicate between services, but this a separate thing, just like what this picture tries to show:

[image]

**Events on the inside is not the same as events on the outside**

Comment: I totally agree. The issue with any command bus is that it introduces a time lag between the command inception and its execution. In the majority of cases, those who invoke commands demand an answer if the command was successfully executed or not. By externalising command handling, you'd start dealing with concerns like informing the invoker about the execution result using events, which just adds complexity.